# list words from file using shell script in alphabetical order and with no punctuation

Tags: bash, shell

I am using Shell script and bash commands.

I have to generate a list of words that are in alphabetical order from a file which has many sentences in it, i am using song lyrics to work this out on. I can return each word in alphabetical order but it still includes some apostrophes, question marks and full stops. to do this I use:

```
cat lyrics01.txt | tr "\"' " '\n' | sort -u >> lyrics01.wl
```

I know this tells the list to go down after each space and apostrophe but I need it to delete the punctuation and simply be the words in an alphabetical order.

I have tried implementing this part:

```
-d ',.;:-+=()'
```

after the 'tr' from my original code but it will not work. Any help for a simpler way or even to solve this would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you want lines split on words but not split on punctuation so that "The world isn't fair." becomes

```
The
world
isnt
fair
```

and not

```
The
world
isn
t
fair
<blank line>
```

the following should do what you want

```
sed 's/[[:punct:]]*//g;s/ /\n/g' lyrics01.txt | sort -u >> lyrics01.wl
```

Comment: @etanresiner  What is telling the command to not output any punctuation? e.g an apostrophe or a question mark ?

Comment: `[:punct:]` is a character class that means all punctuation. The first part of the sed command `s/[[:punct:]]*//g` says to match any and all punctuation (`/[[:punct:]]*/`) and replace it with the empty string (`//`).

Comment: Aaah I understand now, thanks again for helping me. I would upvote your answer but I do not have 15 reputation yet unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

Try sed as below:

```
sed 's/\([[:punct:] ]\)/\n/g' lyrics01.txt | sort -u >> lyrics01.wl
```

This will remove any punctuation marks or space and replace it with new line character.

Comment: Glad it worked. Please accept the answer if it helped, so it gets closed and may be helpful in future to someone else.

Answer (score 0):

All of the examples seem to remove the single quote from the word "isn't"
If that is not what you want, I've tested and come up with this :

```
$ cat test.txt
The
world
isn't
fair.

Isn't it ?

 $ sed "s/ /\n/g" test.txt | sed "s/[[:punct:]]$/\n/g" | grep .
The
world
isn't
fair
Isn't
it
$
```

It's not sorted, but this is to show you can retain punctionation if not at the end